# Pandas: Difficulty Adding New Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, `numeric_df`, with a bunch of columns.  I have this function:

```
def textstat_stats(text):
    difficulty = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(text)
    grade_difficulty = textstat.flesch_kincaid_grade(text)
    gfog = textstat.gunning_fog(text)
    smog = textstat.smog_index(text)
    ari = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)
    cli = textstat.coleman_liau_index(text)
    lwf = textstat.linsear_write_formula(text)
    dcrs = textstat.dale_chall_readability_score(text)
    return pd.Series([difficulty, grade_difficulty, gfog, smog, ari, cli, lwf, dcrs])
```

which returns a Pandas Series.  Now I'm trying this:

```
numeric_df[['difficulty', 'grade_difficulty','gfog','smog','ari','cli','lwf','dcrs']] = textstat_stats(text)
```

However, I get this Error:

```
KeyError: "['difficulty' 'grade_difficulty' 'gfog' 'smog' 'ari' 'cli' 'lwf' 'dcrs'] not in index"
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `numeric_df.loc`?

Comment: @BallpointBen How would you recommend I use it?

Comment: `numeric_df.loc[['difficulty', 'grade_difficulty', ... ]]`

Comment: @bclayman - I would like test my solution, but it is relly problematic. what is `text`? `Series`, `list`, `array`, column of `df`? Also variables like `gfog` return `list` or scalar?

Comment: `text` is just a string and each function within `textstat_stats` gives back a float, so you end up with a Pandas Series of floats

Comment: Hmmm, and my solution works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need add index to `Series` which create columns names:

```
def textstat_stats(text):
    difficulty = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(text)
    grade_difficulty = textstat.flesch_kincaid_grade(text)
    gfog = textstat.gunning_fog(text)
    smog = textstat.smog_index(text)
    ari = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)
    cli = textstat.coleman_liau_index(text)
    lwf = textstat.linsear_write_formula(text)
    dcrs = textstat.dale_chall_readability_score(text)
    idx = ['difficulty', 'grade_difficulty','gfog','smog','ari','cli','lwf','dcrs']
    return pd.Series([difficulty, grade_difficulty, gfog, smog, ari, cli, lwf, dcrs], 
                     index=idx)

df = textstat_stats(text)
print (df)
```